# Pattern matching to extract string matching conditions

Tags: regex, r

I am trying to extract a string matching a pattern in a string. To make sense:

```
 x <- "this.is.fairly//Whatit.is/path/IDbeginUntilhere7/seenit"
```

The objective is of the regex is to return: `IDbeginUntilhere`. I tried this:

```
 str <- regmatches(x, gregexpr("^I.*7$", x))
```

which I understand it doesn't work since the `I` is located in the middle of the string. The question may be too simple, but I'd appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: Omit the ^ and the $.  These specify that the pattern starts at the beginning and ends at the end of the string.

Comment: Thanks. Well the question is really simple then!

Comment: better if it's non-greedy `str <- regmatches(x, gregexpr("^I.*?7$", x))` or `str <- regmatches(x, gregexpr("^I[^I]*7$", x))`

Comment: I'd use the `stringr` package as it's much cleaner and easier to read: `str_extract(x, "I.*?7")`.

Comment: Perhaps you should specify more rules, as to why it should/shouldn't match `"Is/InbeginUntilhere7"` in `"Whatit.Is/InbeginUntilhere7/s"`

Comment: Thanks guys, could you post the suggestions to close the question. @ Mariano: I corrected a typo in the question. The pattern is `IDbeginUntilhere` and I thought the conditions begin with `I` and end with `7` were sufficient. We could also require the string to fall between the `/`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is clear the main issue is the anchors: start of string `^` and end of string `$`.

The secondary issue is the greedy dot that will also match across `/` delimited subparts (i.e. will match the whole `Id7/Not-to-match7` instead of `Id7`).

You need to use something like

```
str <- regmatches(x, gregexpr("I[^/]*7", x))
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zC2xZ1/1)

If you do not need the `7`, you need to use a look-ahead, and a Perl-like regex:

```
str <- regmatches(x, gregexpr("I[^/]*(?=7)", x, perl=TRUE))
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/zC2xZ1/2)